# Pyspark - If char exists, then split and return 1st and last element after concatination, else return existing

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to create a function, which takes in a column name and returns col after processing the data.

One of the functionalities I'm stuck at is as below

If `/` is present in the input

- Split the given input on `/`
- Select first element and last element after split
- If length of first element is `3` or `10` then process, else make col value to null
- If length of last element is `7` or `10` then process, else make col value to null

If `/` is not present in the input

- Take the first 10 chars from the input

Below is my function. Any direct processing on df can also help?

```
def phone_number_processor(col):
    if isinstance(col, str):
        col = F.col(col)
    remove_unnecessary_chars = "[^0-9/]"
    col = F.regexp_replace(col, remove_unnecessary_chars, '')
    col = F.when(F.length(col) <= 10, '').otherwise(col)  # ignore if length less than 10    
    ...

    # if input has '/', then
    # ?????

    # if input doesn't have '/' then
    col = F.substring(col, 1, 10)  # get first 10 chars

    ...
    return col
```

sample output:

```
df.withColumn('PROCESSED_PHONE', phone_number_processor('PHONE')).show()
```

```
+----------------+---------------+
|           PHONE|PROCESSED_PHONE|
+----------------+---------------+
|      1234567890|     1234567890| #-> as is
|123/2345/1234567|     1231234567| #-> first and last elements after split with '/'
|     123/1234567|     1231234567| #-> same as above
|       123/12345|           null| #-> since length last element after split is != 7
|    1234/1234567|           null| #-> since length first element after split is != 3
+----------------+---------------+
```

PS. I've tried to use spark functions - [contains](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.contains.html), [split](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.split.html) however I'm not able to do what I want. I've been working on this for quite sometime, any inputs/suggestions are appreciated as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to define UDF function when you can actually do the same using only Spark builtin functions. Simply split the column `PHONE` then using some `when` expressions on first and last elements of the resulting array get the desired output like this:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1234567890",), ("123/2345/1234567",), ("123/1234567",), ("123/12345",), ("1234/1234567",)], ["PHONE"])

df1 = df.withColumn("split", F.split("PHONE", "/")) \
    .withColumn("first_part", F.element_at("split", 1)) \
    .withColumn("last_part", F.element_at("split", -1)) \
    .withColumn(
        "PROCESSED_PHONE",
        F.when(
            F.size("split") == 1,
            F.substring("first_part", 0, 10)
        ).otherwise(
            F.concat(
                F.when(F.length("first_part") == 3, F.col("first_part")),
                F.when(F.length("last_part") == 7, F.col("last_part"))
            )
        )
).drop("first_part", "last_part", "split")

df1.show()

#+----------------+---------------+
#|           PHONE|PROCESSED_PHONE|
#+----------------+---------------+
#|      1234567890|     1234567890|
#|123/2345/1234567|     1231234567|
#|     123/1234567|     1231234567|
#|       123/12345|           null|
#|    1234/1234567|           null|
#+----------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks, It helps. However I'm trying to create a function  so that I can use it in a package, NOT UDF though. The constraint I've kept is to do it without using df explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@blackbishop's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70824769/7445772), created the function if you are interested

```
def phone_number_validator(col):
    if isinstance(col, str):
        col = F.col(col)
    remove_unnecessary_chars = "[^0-9/]"
    col = F.regexp_replace(col, remove_unnecessary_chars, '')
    col = F.when(F.length(col) <= 10, '').otherwise(col)  # ignore if length less than 10    

    split_col = F.split(col, '/')
    first_part= F.element_at(split_col, 1)
    last_part = F.element_at(split_col, -1)
    col = F.when(
                F.size(split_col) == 1 & F.length(col) >= 10,
                F.substring(col, 1, 10) # get first 10 chars
            ).otherwise(
                F.concat(
                    F.when(F.length(first_part) == 3, first_part),
                    F.when(F.length(last_part ) == 7, last_part ),
                    )  # concatenate any string with a NULL, will result in NULL
                )
    return col
```

Usage:

```
df = df.withColumn('PROCESSED_PHONE', phone_number_validator('PHONE'))
```